# I have a youtube video on my page - how can I see play events on Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics, wix

I have a youtube video embedded on my website.  How do I see how many play events happened on each day, from which sources etc?

I use Wix, Google Analytics and Google Tag Manager.

Comment: Wix doesn't allow you to edit custom JavaScript into your pages.  It is going to be hard to implement anything.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I've hardly used Wix, but there are several threads, like [this one](https://www.wix.com/corvid/forum/community-discussion/how-to-add-javascript-to-wix-pages) that appear to suggest it is possible to add custom JavaScript? (Although maybe it's not as simple as pasting some JavaScript - might have to do it a "Wix way"?!)

Comment: It looks like Wix is slighly better than last time I used it.   In any case, it might be able to be done through Google Tag Manager.

Answer (score 1):

It *should* be doable with GTM (not got a WIX setup to test on atm).

**In GTM, enable all the Built-in Video variables.**

[image]

**Create a Lookup Table Variable.**

1. For the Input Variable enter {{Video Status}}
2. 1st table row, enter start as input and Start Playing Video as output.
   2nd table row, enter progress as input and Reached {{Video Percent}}% as output.
   3rd table row, enter complete as input and Reached Video End as output.
   [image]

**Create Trigger: Trigger Type > Youtube Video**

1. To configure the trigger, click the *Start* and *Complete* options.
2. For *Progress* select *Percentages* and enter 25, 50, 75 into the provided field.
3. Under the *Advanced* option, select *Add JavaScript API support to all YouTube videos*.
4. *Enable this trigger on*: DOM Ready (gtm.dom).
5. *This trigger fires on*: All Videos
   [image]

**Create Univ. GA Event Tag**
Track type > Event
Event Category > Youtube
Event Action > {{Lookup - Video Status}}
Event Label > {{Video Title}} - {{Video URL}}
Attach the Youtube trigger created in previous steps
[image]